# Parse an XML string in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse the following string to obtain the `orderNo`

```java
String requestBody="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ShipmentList><Shipment ActualShipmentDate="2018-06-26T11:25:00+05:30" DocumentType="0005" TotalWeight="55.5" TotalWeightUOM="LB" TrackingNo="9461236897846412938163"><ShipmentLines><ShipmentLine OrderNo="1529904772887" PrimeLineNo="1" Quantity="3" SubLineNo="1"/><ShipmentLine OrderNo="1529904772887" PrimeLineNo="2" Quantity="3" SubLineNo="1"/><ShipmentLine OrderNo="1529904772887" PrimeLineNo="3" Quantity="3" SubLineNo="1"/><ShipmentLine OrderNo="1529904772887" PrimeLineNo="4" Quantity="3" SubLineNo="1"/><ShipmentLine OrderNo="1529904772887" PrimeLineNo="5" Quantity="3" SubLineNo="1"/></ShipmentLines><Extn ExtnPackageASN="55538770655551006451" ExtnPackageID="6247442951596360944" ExtnPackLength="25.0" ExtnLengthUOM="IN" ExtnPackWidth="20.0" ExtnWidthUOM="IN" ExtnPackHeight="16.0" ExtnHeightUOM="IN" ExtnCarrierMethodId="83"/></Shipment></ShipmentList>";

NodeList nl = null;
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(requestBody);
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ShipmentList/Shipment/ShipmentLines/ShipmentLine[@OrderNo]");
    nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
} catch (XPathExpressionException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tried using the above code snippet but it isn't helping.
Can someone let me know what's the mistake?

Comment: what issues are you facing?

Comment: *"i have tried using the above code"* The above code doesn't compile, so how could you have tried using it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts with the unescaped quotes in your XML string.  Then how the string is parsed into a `Document` object. `Document doc = builder.parse(requestBody);` is calling the `DocumentBuilder.parse(String uri)` version where the uri is the location of the XML you're wanting to parse.

Since you have a `String` that you want to parse as XML, you have to pass the `DocumentBuilder` an `InputSource` object like `Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(requestBody)));`

This will get your string into your `Document` object

Now we have to fix how you're accessing the attribute `OrderNo` in the `ShipmentLine` element. To do this change `XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ShipmentList/Shipment/ShipmentLines/ShipmentLine[@OrderNo]");` to `XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ShipmentList/Shipment/ShipmentLines/ShipmentLine/@OrderNo");` and you should now get a `NodeList` that you can iterate through.

### Code with changes

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String requestBody = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>"
                + "<ShipmentList>"
                + "<Shipment ActualShipmentDate=\"2018-06-26T11:25:00+05:30\" DocumentType=\"0005\" TotalWeight=\"55.5\" TotalWeightUOM=\"LB\" TrackingNo=\"9461236897846412938163\">"
                + "<ShipmentLines>"
                + "<ShipmentLine OrderNo=\"1529904772887\" PrimeLineNo=\"1\" Quantity=\"3\" SubLineNo=\"1\"/>"
                + "<ShipmentLine OrderNo=\"1529904772887\" PrimeLineNo=\"2\" Quantity=\"3\" SubLineNo=\"1\"/>"
                + "<ShipmentLine OrderNo=\"1529904772887\" PrimeLineNo=\"3\" Quantity=\"3\" SubLineNo=\"1\"/>"
                + "<ShipmentLine OrderNo=\"1529904772887\" PrimeLineNo=\"4\" Quantity=\"3\" SubLineNo=\"1\"/>"
                + "<ShipmentLine OrderNo=\"1529904772887\" PrimeLineNo=\"5\" Quantity=\"3\" SubLineNo=\"1\"/>"
                + "</ShipmentLines>"
                + "<Extn ExtnPackageASN=\"55538770655551006451\" ExtnPackageID=\"6247442951596360944\" ExtnPackLength=\"25.0\" ExtnLengthUOM=\"IN\" ExtnPackWidth=\"20.0\" ExtnWidthUOM=\"IN\" ExtnPackHeight=\"16.0\" ExtnHeightUOM=\"IN\" ExtnCarrierMethodId=\"83\"/>"
                + "</Shipment>"
                + "</ShipmentList>";

        NodeList nl = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(requestBody)));
            XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ShipmentList/Shipment/ShipmentLines/ShipmentLine/@OrderNo");
            nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            // Output NodeList
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println(nl.item(i));
            }
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
OrderNo="1529904772887"
OrderNo="1529904772887"
OrderNo="1529904772887"
OrderNo="1529904772887"
OrderNo="1529904772887"
```

Comment: To expand on the XPath problem that @shar1er80 fixed, in the original code the xpath statement was selecting the ShipmentLine elements that contain an OrderNo attribute. This is because the square brackets - /ShipmentLine[@OrderNo] - are defining a filter.  The change to using a path step instead - /ShipmentLine/@OrderNo - means that you are now selecting the OrderNo attribute from the ShipmentLine element.

Comment: @RajgauriKhemnar If my answer solved your question, kindly check so your question is marked answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
  DocumentBuilder builder;
  Document doc = null;
  try {
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = builder.parse("C:/shipment.xml");
    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    try {
      XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/ShipmentList/Shipment/ShipmentLines/ShipmentLine");
      NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
      for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = nodes.item(i);
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
          System.out.println("OrderNo :" + eElement.getAttribute("OrderNo"));
        }
      }
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `"` character must be escaped as `\"` in Java String. requestBody String must look like:
`String requestBody="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ...` and so on.

Then main mistake:

`Document doc = builder.parse(requestBody);`

builder parses not String but URL represented by that String.
 So, use `InputStream` instead as example:

```
Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestBody.getBytes()));
```

and you will get your five `<ShipmentLine>` nodes.